# To find the arrangement of given letters so that there is fixed number of transition between them.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-geometry

A 10 letter word is composed of $P,\ Q,\ R,\ S$. The problem is to find the number of arrangements of these letters which could lead to a fixed number of transitions between each pair of letters.

Example,  consider the following arrangement of $P,\ Q,\ R,\ S$ given as 
$PQPRSPQRSS$ has $3\ P$, $2\ Q$, $2\ R$, $3\ S$ has $3$ transitions between $P$ and $Q$, $1$ transition between $P$ and $R$, $1$ transition between $P$ and $S$, $2$ transition between $R$ and $S$ and $1$ transition between $Q$ and $R$.

The question here is to find the number of ways it can be arranged so that the transition between alphabets remains conserved.

Comment: By alphabet do you mean letter?

Comment: In the above question, I have 10  letter word comprising of P,Q,R,S as given. The problem is to find all the combinations which maintains same number of transitions between the letters as given in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a $4 \times 4$ symmetric matrix $M$ with entries $m_{ij}$ and diagonal entries $1$.
I'll label the indices $1,2,3,4$ as $P,Q,R,S$.  Each entry
of $M^{9}$ is a polynomial of total degree $ \le 9$ in the $m_{ij}$, where the coefficient of each monomial in $M^9_{ij}$ gives the number of $10$-letter words starting with $i$, ending with $j$, and with the numbers of transitions specified by the monomial.  Thus for the number with $3$ transitions between $P$ and $Q$, $1$ between $P$ and $R$, $1$ between $P$ and $S$, $1$ between $Q$ and $R$, $2$ between $R$ and $S$, and $0$ for the other pairs, you would take the coefficient of $m_{PQ}^3 m_{PR} m_{PS} m_{QR} m_{RS}^2$.  Since you don't care where you start and end, add these for all $i,j$.  Using Maple I get $288$.

Comment: can u give me some reference so that I can understand the solution well.